# What is the meaning of `meta` when define SemanticMetadata in SysML 2

Tags: sysml, sysml2

Say we have such model written in SysML v2 (taken from sysml domain library, the source is in [causionConnections](https://github.com/Systems-Modeling/SysML-v2-Release/blob/ea55c154de2fcec6c0458571ca18b3dd452dc409/sysml.library/Domain%20Libraries/Cause%20and%20Effect/CausationConnections.sysml#L12) and [CauseAndEffect](https://github.com/Systems-Modeling/SysML-v2-Release/blob/ea55c154de2fcec6c0458571ca18b3dd452dc409/sysml.library/Domain%20Libraries/Cause%20and%20Effect/CauseAndEffect.sysml#L8)):

```
    abstract occurrence causes[*] {
        doc /* Occurrences that are causes. */
    }
    
    abstract occurrence effects[*]  {
        doc /* Occurrences that are effects. */
    }
    metadata def <cause> CauseMetadata :> SemanticMetadata {
        doc
        /*
         * CauseMetadata identifies a usage as being a cause occurrence.
         * It is intended to be used to tag the cause ends of a Multicausation.
         */
         
        ref :>> annotatedElement : SysML::Usage;
        ref :>> baseType = causes as SysML::Usage;
    }
    metadata def CausationMetadata {
        doc
        /*
         * CausationMetadata allows for the specification of additional metadata about
         * a cause-effect connection definition or usage.
         */
         
        ref :> annotatedElement : SysML::ConnectionDefinition;
        ref :> annotatedElement : SysML::ConnectionUsage;
        
        attribute isNecessary : Boolean default false {
        }
        
        attribute isSufficient : Boolean default false {
        }
        
        attribute probability : Real[0..1] {
        }   
    }
    // !some model element is omited for simplicity, 
    //the `causations` is an abstract ConnectionUsage.

    metadata def <causation> CausationSemanticMetadadata :> CausationMetadata, SemanticMetadata {
        doc
        /*
         * CausationMetadata is SemanticMetadata for a Causation connection.
         */
         
        ref :>> baseType = causations meta SysML::Usage;
    }
```

My question is: why the `as` operator is used in the first MetadataDefinition `cause`, while the `meta` operator is used in the second MetadataDefinition `causation` ?
In my opinion the operator seems no meaning here.

What does the operator `as` and `meta` do and why are the difference?